# C - Using bitwise operators to determine if all even bits are set to 1

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Hi I am having trouble getting this function to work. Basically, the the function should return a 1 if all even place bits are 1 and 0 otherwise. This program always prints 0 for some reason.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int allEvenBits(int);

int main() {
        printf("%d\n", allEvenBits(0xFFFFFFFE));
        return 0;
}

int allEvenBits(int X) {
        return !((X & 0x55555555) ^ 0x55555555);
}
```

Comment: try with unsigned int in place of int.

Comment: You have a typo... `int all**Event**Bits(int);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are checking the **odd bits** for the even should be with `0xAAAAAAAA`:

```
const unsigned int ODD_BITS_SET = 0x55555555;
const unsigned int EVEN_BITS_SET = 0xAAAAAAAA;
unsigned int allOddBits(unsigned int X) { return (X & ODD_BITS_SET) == ODD_BITS_SET; }
unsigned int allEvenBits(unsigned int X) { return (X & EVEN_BITS_SET) == EVEN_BITS_SET; }
```

Better to give a name to the magic number.

Comment: This would probably work better if you replaced `int` with `unsigned int`.

Comment: Update, yes, `unsigned types` are better when working with bit operations, thx.

Comment: What do you consider the least-significant bit to be: odd or even?  From my POV, the LSbit is in the power(2,0) position and 0 is even.  There may not be a right/wrong here, just seeking your POV.

Comment: **odd** - is the `first bit`, according the the tested number in the question and the indication that the result was `0` and not `1` as expected, let me to this thinking.

Comment: @NetVipeC Makes sense.  From my POV, OP code was correct as is.  Your interpretation, considering OP's question, is surely right for him. +1

Comment: For fun, thought of a method to calculate `ODD_BITS_SET` from `UINT_MAX`: `const unsigned int ODD_BITS_SET = (UINTMAX/3)&1 ? (UINTMAX/3) : (UINTMAX/3)*2 + 1;`.  Works for 255, 511, 1023, etc.

Comment: you could calculated `EVEN_BITS_SET` later, using `ODD_BITS_SET << 1`, with `constexpr` in C++11 initializing the two in compile time is easy. The `else` branch of the `?:` in what case appear?